# Asking for help in proving a result related to Mangoldt function in number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying exercises of ch-4 of Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory and in 1 question I am struck. This question uses following condition

> Can it be proved that $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac {\Lambda(n) } { n} $ = log (x) +O(1) ?

Due to Mangoldt function sum will be calculated only on prime values but I am not able to get desired result. Can you please help?

Comment: The Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)$ returns $log(p)$ for  $n=p^{k}$ if $p$ is prime. Therefore not only for primes but also prime powers.

Comment: @Martin Hopf ya sorry!!

Answer (score 3):

$$\log(n!) = n\log n+O(n)$$
$$=\sum_{p^k \le n} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor\log p=n \sum_{p^k \le n} \frac{\log p}{p^k}+O(\sum_{p^k \le n} \log p) $$
Where $\sum_{p^k \le n} \log p=O(n)$ from $\log 4^n \sim \log {2n\choose n}\ge \log \prod_{p\in (n,2n]} p$.

Comment: Kindly give a proof of statement log(n!)=  n log n +O(n)

Comment: $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_k^{k+1} \log k dt=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_k^{k+1} (\log t+O(1/t)) dt$ $= (n+1) \log (n+1)-(n+1)+O(\log n)$

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that
$$n!=\prod_{p\;\mathrm{prime}} p^{j(n,p)}=\prod_{\substack{p\;\mathrm{prime}\\p\leq n}} p^{j(n,p)}\quad\mathrm{where}\quad j(n,p)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{p^m}\bigg\rfloor$$
Therefore we obtain
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \ln(n)=\ln\Bigg(\prod_{\substack{p\;\mathrm{prime}\\p\leq x}} p^{j(\lfloor x\rfloor,p)}\Bigg)=\sum_{\substack{p\;\mathrm{prime}\\p\leq x}} j(\lfloor x\rfloor,p)\ln(p)=\sum_{\substack{p\;\mathrm{prime}\\p^m\leq x}} \bigg\lfloor \frac{x}{p^m}\bigg\rfloor\ln(p)=\sum_{n\leq x} \bigg\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\bigg\rfloor\Lambda(n)$$
since $\ln(1)=0$ and for any real number $x$ and any positive integer $n$, we have $\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor/n\rfloor=\lfloor x/n\rfloor$. Now we use the equivalent statement of the Prime Number Theorem, namely the asymptotic formula for Chebyshev's $\psi$-function
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)=O(x)$$
If we remove the floor function in the last sum, we have
\begin{align*}\begin{split} &\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{x}{n}\Lambda(n)<\sum_{n\leq x} \bigg\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\bigg\rfloor\Lambda(n)+\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)+O(x)\\ &\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{x}{n}\Lambda(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)+O(x) \end{split}\end{align*}
since for any real number $x$, we have $x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1$. Now we use the asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)=x\ln(x)+O(x)$, therefore we obtain
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{x}{n}\Lambda(n)=x\ln(x)+O(x)$$
Dividing by $x$ on both sides and it follows.

Comment: The game is to avoid using the PNT when it is not needed

Comment: @reuns This is my first time answering a question, sorry if I don't know the rules on MSE.

Comment: It is not a rule, sometimes it is fine to use the PNT to give more insights, but when there is a 3 lines elementary solution it is better not to use any complicated theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting! By the way your solution is great!

Comment: @求石莫得 Can you please tell how you deduced the inequality "$\begin{align*}\begin{split} &\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{x}{n}\Lambda(n)<\sum_{n\leq x} \bigg\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\bigg\rfloor\Lambda(n)+\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)+O(x)\\ &\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{x}{n}\Lambda(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)+O(x) \end{split}\end{align*}$ involoving greatest integer function in here?  ( I am talking about 1st line ( ehich is the only inequality in question)